# Do I need Express.js to use Angular.js with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and at the moment I am trying to wrap my head around template engines. It seems like all the tutorials I find on using Angular.js with Node.js are always accompanied with Express.js.

**Do I need Express.js to use Angular.js with Node.js? If so, why?**

**What is the relationship between Express and Node/Angular?**

**What in the world is a template engine?**

**Why did I not need a template engine for PHP?**

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to use Express for Angular. You could use another framework or just the plain node.js core http/https server directly. Express just incorporates abstractions and conventions on top of the built-in node.js http/https server to make it easier to write your backend logic.

See wikipedia for both a good [overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor) of what a template engine is and a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) of example template engines.

Template engines aren't necessary to generate output, but they can certainly aid you in that process by making it easier/simpler to compose output, instead of manually concatenating or echoing a bunch of strings for example. PHP kind of has a "template" built-in, in that output buffering is used such that you can just inject `<?php ?>` blocks anywhere in the output. This is similar to many template engines, including [ejs](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs), except ejs can save the template as a reusable function instead of throwing it all away once the request is done).